Why are SSDs less prone to file corruption caused by sudden shutdowns?
I lived 8 years with HDDs. Every time when there was a power outage, or for whatever reason I had to force-shutdown the computer by turning off the PSU or pushing that fancy-yet-dangerous restart button on the PC case, my heart would race in fear for what would happen next: will Windows give me an error during or after boot that my computer needs repair, or will it just boot normally? 70% of the times it was the first case.
Living with SSDs for about 9 months so far (the terrible startup speed of Visual Studio 2022 with HDDs finally forced me to buy an SSD), during this time the computer had around 8 occurrences of sudden unexpected shutdowns and none of them resulted in Windows boot errors or critical system files corruption (by habit, I tried SFC and DISM every time to make sure the OS is healthy).
Counting the amount of incidents and getting surprised that none of them forced me to repair or change my Windows installation, I searched online a bit about it but all the topics I encountered were about the durability of SSDs and similar topics but not related to what I'm describing (I’m lazy btw, didn't dig too much online), so I decided to start a topic about it on my own.
So, does anybody know and care to explain for everybody's knowledge that why this happens? Is it because of the fast nature of an SSD that it gets enough time to complete I/O cycles before it loses power that results in avoiding file corruption?
I think it’s also worth mentioning that I used GPT with SSD but always used MBR partition table with HDDs.

Also, at a guess, their write speed is high enough to finish writing data from cache before the capacitors run down.

Invest in a UPS then you will not have to worry about sudden power outages and you can perform a controlled shutdown.  Most UPS even support software to do that shutdown automatically.

Your question is based purely on anecdotal experience. You're comparing apples to oranges. The situations and hardware of the past 8 years are not comparable to recent experience. You're not comparing equivalent events under anything close to controlled conditions. You're trying to use just one difference (out of many) to explain perceived outcomes.   "I think it’s also worth mentioning that I used GPT ..." - Completely irrelevant.

@sawdust I'm not comparing technology advances (I know they play a part in this) from 8 years ago to nowadays tech, I'm just asking for what kind of logic is behind this.

The primary advantage that an SSD has over an HHD to avoid data corruption due to a power cut is simply because of the use of the FTL, Flash Translation Layer.
The time interval that exposes a sector of an HDD to corruption during a write is the time to actually write that one sector to the media while the platter is rotating. The (long) access/seek time of an HDD is irrelevant to this issue because there's no corruption possible during this prelude to the actual write. But once the sector is located and the write commences, the write operation must complete and end with the writing of the ECC, or else the sector cannot be read & validated. This is a well-understood liability of HDDs.
The time to write a logical block (aka sector) of an SSD depends significantly on the availability of a previously-erased logical block. Worst-case scenarios are described as the write amplification problem.
But regardless of the actual time required to write a logical block to NAND flash, the SSD does not have to expose this newly-written block to the host until after the write is actually complete and then mapped to the specified LBA.
In other words, the HDD performs the write operation on the actual physical sector, and therefore has a rather long vulnerability interval.
Whereas the SDD has an FTL, and will perform the write operation on an unmapped/spare block. Only after the write operation is actually complete and successful, does the FTL remap the specified LBA from the old/stale block to the newly written block. The short time to perform this simple remapping of the LB address is the vulnerability interval to acquire a corrupted SSD block. But power-fail logic probably strives to avoid any corruption of the mapping table.

Nothing but a pure coincidence.
Any modern OS has a feature called Write Caching which means that the OS does not flush the data it needs to write to the disk immediately and instead it may wait a bit before doing so, to improve performance and optimize file writes (e.g. to avoid fragmentation).
If you forcefully reset your PC, it makes no difference what type of storage you have, so called "write buffers" will be lost regardless.
What could theoretically alleviate (but not solve completely) this issue is that SSDs/NVMes seek times are effectively zero, which means Windows has a greater chance of successfully flushing data to the disk vs. HDDs.
You can disable Windows Disk write cache completely using the Device Manager and that will make it less likely to deal with this issue (but it won't solve it completely because data flushing is still not instantaneous). Doing so may negatively affect the performance of your SSD/NVMe during high load operations.

"You've seemingly neglected decades of improvements in Windows itself" but its the same Windows version (10 22H2) that was on the HDD and now on the SSD.

You never mentioned it was the same version of Windows and your testimony doesn't look truthful at all: "I lived 8 years with HDDs" vs "Living with SSDs for about 9 months so far". Wildly different time scales and somehow SSD are magically more reliable. No, they are not.

True, I admit my question lacking some information. The last year of that 8 years experience with HDD and so far with SSD's its the same Windows version, just reinstalled. Live'd a total of 3 years with Windows 10 on HDD. "Wildly different time scales and somehow SSD are magically more reliable. No, they are not." didn't expect magic, its a more reliable and stable tech.

SSDs are so much faster.  Instant reading and writing in comparison to an HHD.  Well, not instant but in comparison to an HDD it is.  The likelihood of the drive being caught while writing is small due to the nature of it.  It is simply RAM being used as a disk drive.
